# React useState pre populated from previous component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to create a `Quiz` component rendering one `Question` at time and changing it when the user chooses one of the alternatives.

However, every time it renders the next Question it has already the `chosenOption` variable set from the previous Question. This happens because before I change the Question, I set the new state of the current Question with that `chosenOption` and strangely(to me) this is already set when the next Question component is rendered.

For me, the `setChosenOption` would set only for the current Question and when the Quiz renders the next Question its `chosenOption` would be null initially. I may be missing something from how functional components render... So why is it happening?

Thanks in advance!

```js
const Quiz = () => {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = React.useState(0)
    const [answers, updateAnswers] = React.useState({})
    const numberOfQuestions = questions.length
    const onChoosenOptionCallbackHandler = ({ hasChosenCorrectOption, chosenOption}) => {
        updateAnswers(prevAnswers => ({...prevAnswers, [currentQuestion]: hasChosenCorrectOption }))
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
    }

    return (
        <QuizBackground>
            <QuizContainer>
                <Question
                     question={questions[currentQuestion]}
                     index={currentQuestion}
                     numberOfQuestions={numberOfQuestions}
                     onChoosenOptionCallback={onChoosenOptionCallbackHandler}
                 />
            </QuizContainer>
        </QuizBackground>
    )
}
```

Here, apart from the first Question, the `'Chosen Option: '` log always show the `chosenOption` from the previous Question rendered and not null.

```js
const Question = ({ question, index, numberOfQuestions, onChoosenOptionCallback }) => {
    const [chosenOption, setChosenOption] = React.useState(null)
    console.log('Chosen Option: ', chosenOption)
    const hasChosenCorrectOption = chosenOption !== null ? (chosenOption == answer) : false

    const selectOption = (optionIndex) => {
        setChosenOption(optionIndex)
        console.log('SELECTED: ', optionIndex, hasChosenCorrectOption, chosenOption)
        onChoosenOptionCallback({ hasChosenCorrectOption, optionIndex })
    }

    return (
          {/* I removed other parts not relevant. The RadioOption goes inside a map() from the question alternatives */}
          <RadioOption
              questionName={questionName}
              option={option}
              chosen={chosenOption === index}
              onSelect={() => selectOption(index)}
              key={index}
          />
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to assign a `key` to each `Question` component you're rendering in your map iteration, this way they'll re-render correctly

Comment: specifically, using `index` as key leads to React misidentifying components if the order of the mapped array  changes. Use a unique property of the mapped elements as key. ( eg. id, etc). see: [React#Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks for the tip! I initially didn't set any `key` to the `Question` since it is not being rendered through any map, only one at a time. When the `currentQuestion` changes then I pass new props to the component. But putting `key` did solved it! I thought since the props are changing React would render a new `Question` with its `chosenOption` to null but it didnt.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks as well! I ended up doing like you suggested and put another `key` instead of using the index.

Comment: React doesn't unmount and remount a component of the same type just because a prop changes, because it has no way of knowing that any given prop is so important it changes the identity of the component—`key` does that, with or without a loop, and also lets React reorder components within a loop without remounting. N.B.: even if you use `React.memo` to memoize a component, that will only short-circuit unnecessary renders, not cause a unmount/remount when the props change.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey Thanks for the explanation! That was my wrong assumption then. I thought it would create another component if any of the props changed. Didn't know the `key` was used for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a result of not assigning `key`s to your `Question` components, that are being rendered using a `map` function.

The omission of [proper keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) (i.e. a unique property of each element in the rendered array) results in all sorts of weird behaviours, such as what you were describing.

The reason for that is that React uses these indices to optimize, by re-rendering only the components whose props were changed. Without the keys the whole process isn't working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link! Really appreciate :)